# Problems with gatsby-source-contentful plugin options, not able to access required tokens

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gatsby

I am unable to deploy this project due to `gatsby build` can't access the required tokens from the env file.
It is working fine when I run the command "yarn develop".

It throws this error:
[image: cli screenshot]

It doesn't work in these conditions:
When I run `gatsby develop` or `gatsby build`.

Due to this, running `yarn run deploy` doesn't work as expected.

Here's my package.json

[image: package.json screenshot]

Here's my gatsby-config.js:

[image: gatsby-config.js screenshot]

Please help me to resolve this issue.